# Django CRUD System without django.forms passing {{ id }} to view function

Tags: python, django, django-templates, crud

I'm programming a CRUD (without using django.forms or generic forms)
I can't pass id value from toUpArti() to updateArti()
can anyone tell me how or mention another way to solve this problem

---

article/views.py:

```
def toUpArti(request, arti_id):

    d = ArticleItem.objects.get(id=arti_id)

    return render(request, 'artiUp.html')



def updateArti(request):

    u = ArticleItem.objects.filter(id=x).update(title=request.POST['title'],
                                               body=request.POST['body'])
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/article/')
```

---

Comment: Can you please elaborate your problem? How does the `updateArti` view get called? What are the url patterns?

Comment: You would need to either pass the id as url parameter, or specify the id in the POST body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your url is something like

```
path('article/<int:arti_id/', views.toUpArit, name='view-article')
```

Then your return should be `HTTPRespoonseRedirect(reverse('view-article', kwargs='arti_id:u.id}))`

Use the [DRY principle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/misc/design-philosophies/#don-t-repeat-yourself-dry)